DynamoDBMappingException: could not invoke null on class
Getting this below error while querying items from DDB. Table already has required annotations & getter and setter methods too with converter logic. But still getting the same error & stucked for last 2 days.
com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: POSTable[ProductIdentificationDetails]; could not unconvert attribute
Caused by: com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMappingException: could not invoke null on class  with value Optional[ProductIdentificationDetails(identificationNumbers=[serialNumber2, serialNumber1, serialNumber3], capturedTime=Fri Apr 12 10:23:38 UTC 2024, userId=32886492417)] of type class java.util.Optional at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$MethodReflect.set(StandardBeanProperties.java:136) ~[AWSPersistenceJavaClient-1.12.x.jar:?] at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.set(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:111) ~[AWSPersistenceJavaClient-1.12.x.jar:?] at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.unconvertAndSet(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:164) ~[AWSPersistenceJavaClient-1.12.x.jar:?] at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.unconvert(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:267) ~[AWSPersistenceJavaClient-1.12.x.jar:?] ... 97 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.StandardBeanProperties$MethodReflect.set(StandardBeanProperties.java:133) ~[AWSPersistenceJavaClient-1.12.x.jar:?] at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.set(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:111) ~[AWSPersistenceJavaClient-1.12.x.jar:?] at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.unconvertAndSet(DynamoDBMapperFieldModel.java:164) ~[AWSPersistenceJavaClient-1.12.x.jar:?] at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.datamodeling.DynamoDBMapperTableModel.unconvert(DynamoDBMapperTableModel.java:267) ~[AWSPersistenceJavaClient-1.12.x.jar:?] ... 97 more
   public void setProductIdentificationDetails(final ProductIdentificationDetails productIdentificationDetails) {
        this.productIdentificationDetails = Optional.ofNullable(productIdentificationDetails);
    }

    @DynamoDBMarshalling(marshallerClass = ProductIdentificationDetailsConverter.class)
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "ProductIdentificationDetails")
    public Optional<ProductIdentificationDetails> getProductIdentificationDetails() {
        log.info("debug : " + this.productIdentificationDetails);
        return this.productIdentificationDetails;
    }

Annotations used on table class
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor (access = AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
@Log4j
@DynamoDBTable


Object converter logic:
@Log4j
public class ProductIdentificationDetailsConverter implements DynamoDBMarshaller<Optional<ProductIdentificationDetails>>
{
    @Override
    public String marshall(final Optional<ProductIdentificationDetails> object) {
        return object.isPresent() ? IonUtility.toString(object.get()) : null;
    }

    @Override
    public Optional<ProductIdentificationDetails> unmarshall(final Class<Optional<ProductIdentificationDetails>> clazz,
            final String serializedObject) {
        try {

            return (StringUtils.isNotEmpty(serializedObject)
                    ? Optional.of(IonUtility.toObject(serializedObject, ProductIdentificationDetails.class))
                    : Optional.empty());
        } catch (final IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("ProductIdentificationDetails De-serialization Failed", e);
        }
    }
}


Did it get resolved , do post the update.
if not share your ProductIdentificationDetails class i think youre missing a setter or setter is not getting invoked
@Setter
@Getter
@NoArgsConstructor
@DynamoDBDocument
this might help

